# how tochange font color of Jfoeinx TextArea

Tags: css, javafx

i'm using Jfoeinx TextArea and i want to change the  font color (white by default )
i ve tried -fx-background-color but it didn't work 
thnx

```
AnchorPane root=new AnchorPane();
        JFXTextArea text =new JFXTextArea();
        root.getChildren().add(text);
        text.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#000000");
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 789));
         primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: you want to color font not the background so use `-fx-text-fill`

Comment: thank you and for the color of the box where i write the text it's always white      i ve tried fx-background-color to change it but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try with `-fx-text-fill` as this is how you often set svg text color

Comment: thank you and for the color of the box where i write the text it's always white i ve tried fx-background-color to change it but it didn't work